# SSH: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "id_rsa" from agent: agent refused operation

Tags: ssh

I know questions with the same title have been asked many times, but I still think mine may be different.

I have two PCs, win10 and win7, and an ubuntu18.04 server. **win10 and win7 can both login the server with a shared private key**. **win10 and win7 can login each other with the same private key, too**. With these settings I did two experiments.

(1) From win7 first ssh to win10, then ssh to ubuntu, with two consecutive simple commands. This one succeeds.

```
# win7 powershell
ssh userA@win10 -v
ssh userB@ubuntu -v
```

(2) From win10 first ssh to win7, then ssh to ubuntu.

```
# win10 powershell
ssh userC@win7 -v
ssh userB@ubuntu -v
```

Then I got this error in the second step, which asked me to use password instead. The password authentication works fine, by the way.

```
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA 
SHA256:JFf56HHFG6CPHdGaAxtf0SsrzVXoTlLADCN/zD3DQxw agent
debug1: Server accepts key: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA 
SHA256:JFf56HHFG6CPHdGaAxtf0SsrzVXoTlLADCN/zD3DQxw agent

sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_rsa" from agent: agent refused operation
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
...
debug1: Next authentication method: password
...
```

Solutions I have tried:

(1) Modify permission of the private key and keep myself as the only user that has permission.

(2) Modify ~/.ssh/config and sshd_config file for entries such as `AllowTcpForwarding`, `AllowAgentForwading`, and comment out the `Match Group administrators` part.

(3) Restart sshd service on the hosts.

(4) Run `ssh-add` command to register the key on win7 and win10, and make sure both hosts have a running ssh-agent.

Yet none has fixed the problem.